# Unable to reapply change in feature branch after reverting change in develop

Tags: git

I did the following:

1. Created a feature branch `myBranch` from the development branch `develop`
2. In `myBranch`, created a file `myFile.js`
3. (Accidentally) created and merged a PR from `myBranch` to `develop`
4. In `develop` reverted the accidental merge. This created a new PR that only contained the removal of `myFile.js`
5. Merged the revert into `develop`

Now, the `develop` branch is clean but I am unable to merge `develop` into `myBranch`. It lets me perform the action, but it tries to delete `myFile.js`. I need this file for this feature and I want it to be included.

I tried just removing it from the merge commit, but now every time I try to merge `develop` into `myBranch` it tries to delete it again!

What did I do wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: Please add your best attempt at a branch diagram.

Comment: Here is my best attempt =D https://imgur.com/YKddns5
I've noticed steps. To sum up, now when I try to merge develop into myBranch, it tries to delete myFile.js because the revert PR did it.

Comment: @lpeliberty I reworded your question to be more focused on the actions your performed, the effects, and the issue you see. If you don't like it, you can revert it by clicking on the "edited" text above my name and choosing "rollback" on your original version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue occurs because Git is trying to "help" and only apply changes that need to be applied.

Git doesn't know anything about the changes themselves, it just sees that there are changes and applies them. From Git's perspective, it sees the following:

```
develop    o-----o-C
            \   /   \
myBranch     o-A-B-o-X
```

Commits:

- `A` - File `myFile.js` was added
- `B` - Some additional changes to the file `myFile.js`
- `C` - File `myFile.js` removed (by the revert)
- `X` - The problem

In X, Git detects a conflict - it attempts to apply the current state of `develop` IE make `myFile.js` deleted to the current state of `myBranch`, but it sees that `develop` does not contain the commit `B`, which contains a change to `myFile.js`.

So, how do you fix it?

**Option 1: Resolve the conflict**

1. `git checkout myBranch` - Switch to `myBranch`
2. `git merge develop` - Merge `develop`
3. There are now conflicts
4. `git add myFile.js` - Stage `myFile.js` so the delete is ignored
5. `git merge --continue` - Continue on your merry way
6. `git push` - Push changes to remote branch

The branch diagram stays the same.

**Option 2: Reapply the change**

NOTE: This is not a good fit for the workflow mentioned in the question, but may be useful elsewhere. This is a very bad idea if `develop` has ever (successfully) been merged to `myBranch`.

1. `git checkout myBranch` - Switch to `myBranch`
2. `git rebase develop` - Rebase all the changes from `myBranch` on top of the current `develop`
3. There are (probably) no conflicts, since adding a file will only conflict if the file already exists.
4. `git push -f` - Force push the changes to the remote branch

This results in the following branch diagram:

```
develop    o-o-A-o-C
                    \
myBranch             o-A'-B'-o
```

Here `A'` and `B'` are identical copies of `A` and `B`, but with unique ids. Going forward, it will be perfectly fine to merge between the branches and there will not be conflicts (from this process).

---

Upon re-reading your question, I believe option 1 above will not work for you since you do not have conflicts. At its core, you're facing the same issue and it has the same fix - you need to re-add the file. The simplest solution is to just create a new commit doing just that.

**Option 3: Manually reapply the change**

1. `git checkout myBranch` - Switch to `myBranch`
2. Copy `myFile.js` to a location not tracked by git
3. `git merge develop` - Merge the changes from develop
4. Allow the merge to delete `myFile.js`
5. Commit the merge
6. Copy `myFile.js` back to its original location
7. Commit the "new file" as normal

Comment: Thanks for these nice solutions ! I tried the first but it does not works. The second is not good for me... So I will choose the third ! I did not even think about it ! Thanks for this nice answer !